# Splitting a String containing special characters in to individual characters

Tags: java, regex

I want to parse user input in to individual characters. 
For example, the input

- `Hello! My name is x`

Should be split in:

```
{"H", "e", "l", "l", "o", "!"," ", "M","y"....}
```

Note that I want to keep the whitespace.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this using *String.split*. I've tried searching for regex that would do this but all of them cut off at !.

This is the current code, I'm trying to split the string coming in from the scanner.

```
    public static List<String> getUserInput() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a line of text: ");

        return Arrays.asList(scanner.next().split("")); 
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

try this:
`String[] cs = s.split("");`

Comment: @Lithicas this answer is working, how are you using it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.toCharArray`

This will give you a `char[]` of your string, with whitespace preserved.

Comment: It cuts off at "Hello!" though.

Comment: That's not true.  `toCharArray()` returns the entire string, it doen't cut off anywhere.

Comment: I just tested it. I get the input from scanner.next if that matters.

Comment: We'd need to see your code.  It doesn't cut off.  You must have a bug somewhere else in your program.

Comment: `next()` finds tokens, which by default are cut off at white space.  You want `nextLine()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious why you want to do this. Strings can be read basically as arrays with `charAt()`. You can turn a string into a stream with `StringReader`. You can turn a string into an `IntStream` with `chars()` or `codePoints()`. Or you can just get a copy if its internal character array with `toCharArray()`.

Regarding something you said in the comments about `toCharArray()` or `.split()` cutting off, they don't.  You must have a bug somewhere, please show us your code.

```
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      String test = "Hello! My name is x";
      char[] chars = test.toCharArray();
      System.out.println( Arrays.toString( chars ) );
   }
```

This prints the whole string for me and doesn't cut off.

```
run:
[H, e, l, l, o, !,  , M, y,  , n, a, m, e,  , i, s,  , x]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

**Update:** Regarding your update, `next()` finds tokens, which by default are cut off at white space.  You want `nextLine()`.

```
    return Arrays.asList(scanner.next().split(""));
```

Change to:

```
    return Arrays.asList(scanner.nextLine().split(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the word boundary matcher:

```
assertEquals(3, "a b".split("\\b").length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
String foo = "Hello! My name is x";

for(char c: foo.toCharArray()) {
    //do whatever you want here

    //for example
    System.out.print(c);
}
```

Hope it helps.